# Get All process list with windows Api in python

Tags: python, windows, api, process

I need Simple python Code For Get All process list in Windows 7 with windows api
after show all running process , kill Selected Process(optional) with admin access...

Tnx :X

Comment: Welcome to SO, this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask might help you.

Comment: take a look at psutil: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psutil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely do this via [psutil](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psutil), as James pointed out above. I believe the function you want is `psutil.pids()`. Then you can do the following:

```
p = psutil.Process(pid)
p.terminate()
```

I wrote a rudimentary process monitor / task manager in wxPython that you might find helpful too:

- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2012/07/13/wxpython-creating-your-own-cross-platform-process-monitor-with-psutil/